# Fast switching between ui threads forces app to terminate abruptly

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I am making an flashlight app in which i have placed two toggle buttons ,the functioning of two toggle buttons is

1) to give the strobe(sos) effect . EnableStrobe/DisableStrobe .

2) simple flashlight effect . EnableFlashlight/DisableFlashlight .

if i toggle these ToggleButtons individually or slowly switch between these ToggleBUttonsthen my app is working fine .But on fast Switching these toggle buttons my app terminates abruptly . I have made two thread classes for each ToggleButton .Rest of the things are working ,i feel there is some problem with my onClickListener code .

**onClickListener code in main ui thread**

```
strobebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (flag1 == 1) {
                flasheffect.isflashOn = true;
                flashbutton.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (strobebutton.isChecked()) {
                bw = new Thread(strobeffect);
                bw.start();
                flag2 = 1;
            } else {
                strobeffect.requestStop = true;
            }
        }
    });
    flashbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (flag2 == 1) {
                runner.requestStop = true;
                strobeffect.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (togglebutton1.isChecked()) {
                aw = new Thread(flasheffect);
                aw.start();
                flag1 = 1;
            } else {
                flasheffect.isflashOn = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

**ToggleButton associated with StrobeClass**

```
public class StrobeRunner implements Runnable {
protected StrobeRunner() {
}

public static StrobeRunner getInstance() {
    return (instance == null ? instance = new StrobeRunner() : instance);
}

private static StrobeRunner instance;
public volatile boolean requestStop = false;
public volatile boolean isRunning = false;
public volatile int delay = 10;
public volatile int delayoff = 10;
public volatile StrobeLightConfig controller;
public volatile String errorMessage = "";

public void run() {
    if (isRunning)
        return;

    requestStop = false;
    isRunning = true;

    Camera cam = Camera.open();

    Camera.Parameters pon = cam.getParameters(), poff = cam.getParameters();

    pon.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    poff.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

    while (!requestStop) {
        try {
            cam.setParameters(pon);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            cam.setParameters(poff);
            Thread.sleep(delayoff);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            requestStop = true;
            errorMessage = "Error setting camera flash status. Your device may be unsupported.";
        }
    }
    cam.release();
    isRunning = false;
    requestStop = false;
    controller.mHandler.post(controller.mShowToastRunnable);
}
```

}

**code with FlashEffect class**

```
public class FlashOn implements Runnable {

protected FlashOn() {
}

public static FlashOn getInstance() {
    return (instance == null ? instance = new FlashOn() : instance);
}

private static FlashOn instance;
public volatile StrobeLightConfig control;
public volatile boolean isflashOn = false;
public volatile boolean isRunning = false;
public volatile String errMessage = "";
Parameters param;

public void run() {
    if (isRunning) {
        return;
    }
    isRunning = true;
    isflashOn = false;
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    param = camera.getParameters();
    param.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    while (!isflashOn) {
        try {
            camera.setParameters(param);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            isflashOn = true;
        }
    }
    camera.release();
    isflashOn = false;
    isRunning = false;
}
```

}

logcat

```
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-16457
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146): Process: com.stwalkerster.android.apps.strobelight, PID: 27146
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:364)
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:334)
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146):    at com.stwalkerster.android.apps.strobelight.FlashOn.run(FlashOn.java:28)
10-19 03:37:29.521: E/AndroidRuntime(27146):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

my problem may be silly but i have been stuck on this since quite a while .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use only one Camera object per activity. Because your threads are using different Camera objects as **One thread is trying to open camera when Other one has not yet released it** and fast switching causes `Fail to connect to camera service`.

**Reason:**

According to the **[android camera open documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29)**, a runtime exception is thrown:

> If connection to the camera service fails (for example, if the camera is in use by another process or device policy manager has disabled the camera)

**How Can You Achieve that**:

Make a(*only*) camera object in your Activity and Use  <strike>constructor of Thread classes</strike> getter setter to Pass Camera Object to Runnable classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your next thread is trying to open camera when previous one has not yet released it, add logging to verify it. You might have problem in your thread synchronization code, next thread should always start only once previous one stopped. using ExecutorService should make it simple to implement executing one runnable at the time from queue.

I think you could keep one global to activity Camera object and open it in onStart and release in onPause, or at least synchronize your threads on some global instance or class.